# How to find a file upwardly in Python?

Tags: python

What is the best way to find a file "upwardly" in Python?  (Ideally it would work on Windows too).  E.g.,

```
>>> os.makedirs('/tmp/foo/bar/baz/qux')
>>> open('/tmp/foo/findme.txt', 'w').close()
>>> os.chdir('/tmp/foo/bar/baz/qux')
>>> findup('findme.txt')
'/tmp/foo/findme.txt'
```

As far as I can tell, there isn't anything in the Python standard library (although I'd love to be proven wrong).  Also, googling around didn't turn up much that's definitive; I'm wondering if there's something out there that "everyone" uses.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
import os

def findup(filename):
    drive, thisdir = os.path.splitdrive(os.getcwd())
    while True:
        fullpath = os.path.join(drive, thisdir, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(fullpath):
            return fullpath
        if thisdir == os.path.sep: #root dir
            raise LookupError('file not found: %r' % filename)
        thisdir = os.path.dirname(thisdir)

os.makedirs('/tmp/foo/bar/baz/qux')
open('/tmp/foo/findme.txt', 'w').close()
os.chdir('/tmp/foo/bar/baz/qux')
print findup('findme.txt')
```

Prints:

```
/tmp/foo/findme.txt
```

Also works on Windows. Probably will work on any platform.

Answer (score 1):

The module os.path has what you need, in particular: abspath() (if the path is not absolute), dirname(), isfile(), and join().

```
dir = os.path.curdir()
filename = None
while True:
    filename = os.path.join(dir, 'filename')
    if os.path.isfile(filename):
        break
    updir = os.path.dirname(dir)
    if updir == dir:
        filename = None
        break
    dir = updir
```

Edit: change posixpath to os.path so that this works on Windows.

Edit x2: add code.

Comment: os.isfile() is not a function. Try os.path.isfile().

Answer (score 0):

I found myself in need of a findup function similar to the node.js version as well, opted for a recursive implementation:

```
import os

def findup(filename, dir = os.getcwd()):
    def inner(drive, dir, filename):
        filepath = os.path.join(drive, dir, filename)
        if os.path.isfile(filepath):
            return filepath
        if dir == os.path.sep:
            raise LookupError('file not found: %s' % filename)
        return inner(drive, os.path.dirname(dir), filename)
    drive, start = os.path.splitdrive(os.path.abspath(dir))
    return inner(drive, start, filename)
```