# Search upward for a file in lua?

Tags: lua

How can I search upward from my cwd to find a file?

Essentially, I want the lua version [of this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/899273/how-to-find-a-file-upwardly-in-python).

I want to use my `.luacheckrc` as a root project marker.

I'm using Lua 5.4 without luafilesystem.

Comment: There is no standard Lua function for that, even in LFS.  You should write your own code for this task.  Please start writing it and show where have you stuck.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a dumb version that can only find files (not folders) and doesn't canonicalize paths:

```lua
local function file_exists(path)
    local f = io.open(path, "r")
    if f then
        f:close()
        return true
    end
    return false
end

function find_file_upwards(filename, start_directory)
    assert(filename:sub(-1, -1) ~= '/', "Cannot find folders: Only files are supported.")
    assert(start_directory:sub(-1, -1) == '/', "Folder paths must end with slash: /")
    local dir = start_directory
    for i=1,1000 do
        local fpath = dir .. filename
        if file_exists(fpath) then
            return fpath
        end
        dir = dir .. "../"
    end
end
```

Probably should strip paths off instead of using a loop so it can stop when it hits the root of the filesystem instead of many pointless retries.